# How do I Stop a running runOnUiThread Runnable

Tags: runnable, osmdroid, osmbonuspack

I want to be able to toggle a MyLocationNewOverlay on and off.  My current code is:-

```
    void btnTrack() {
        btnTrack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

        btnTrack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String btnText = btnTrack.getText().toString();
            GpsMyLocationProvider provider = new GpsMyLocationProvider(ctx);
            provider.addLocationSource(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            // My Location Overlay
            MyLocationNewOverlay mysLocationoverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(provider, map);

            if (btnText.equalsIgnoreCase("Start")) {
                /**************************************************************************
                 *      Get and display the current location
                 **************************************************************************/

                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

                mysLocationoverlay.enableMyLocation(); // not on by default
                mysLocationoverlay.setDirectionArrow(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.marker_node), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.marker_poi_default));
                mysLocationoverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                btnTrack.setText("CANCEL");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                map.getOverlays().add(mysLocationoverlay);
            }
            else {
                mysLocationoverlay.disableMyLocation();
                mysLocationoverlay.disableFollowLocation();
                map.getOverlays().remove(mysLocationoverlay);
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                btnTrack.setText("START");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I'm pretty sure that the problem is with the runnable but I can't see any way of terminating that when I toggle the button to 'Cancel'led.

I'm using osmdroid v6.1.0 and osmbonuspack v6.6.0

How can I stop the runnable?

Comment: The runnable shouldn't be a problem. A Runnable by design runs only once. You are also using runOnFirstFix, therefore it should be ok. I am not sure where the problem really is. Try to add some logging (Log.d(...)) and/or use debugger to see if the code is executed properly. If I had to guess maybe you need a `map.invalidate()` call after `map.getOverlays().remove(..)`.

Comment: @Josef - thank you for the quick reply.  However, adding map.invalidate() didn't work.  I wrapped the map.getOverlays().remove(...) in a couple of Log statements and it appears that the remove failed, presumably because the locationOverlay is still active.  Does that sound as if it might be the reason and, if so, how can I fix it?

Comment: Oh, now I see the problem. I'll write a proper response in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a local instance of MyLocationNewOverlay every time the button is clicked.

When the button is clicked for the first time a MyLocationNewOverlay instance is created, activated and added to the map view.

When the button is clicked for the second time, another new instance of MyLocationOverlay is created. This new instance is deactivated and removed from map view - well, not really, since it was never activated nor added.

I would suggest to keep a reference to the MyLocationOverlay instance in your activity (or fragament, denpends on your situation) and create it only the first time the button is clicked (check for null).

Comment: Another note: you also don't need to create GpsMyLocationProvider every time.

Comment: Yes! that's the answer - many thanks.  I removed the GpsMyLocationProvider and MyLocationNewOverlay lines up above the setOnClickListener so that they were instantiated when the button was instantiated.  That did the trick.  Many thanks, once again, for your help and advice.